# simple view using the STL

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, c++17

I want to make a basic 'view' class that is simply a container of const refs to existing objects, with only standard C++ and the STL. I can do this with

```
template<typename T>
using view = vector<reference_wrapper<const T>>
```

Which works nicely with the rest of the STL like the algorithms library. The problem is the user must call .get() on objects in this view to do anything useful (which is annoying usability wise). I'm looking for an easy way of extending this such that the accessors automatically return `const T&` rather than `std::reference_wrapper<const T>`

Can this be done without creating a new `View` class deriving from `vector` and overriding the relevant methods?

Comment: I'd probably create a View class, but rather than deriving from std::vector I would wrap it and expose it through my own accessors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a imperfect solution.

```
class C {
public:
    void fun() { cout << "C::fun();" << endl; }
};

template <class _Ty>
class myreference_wrapper : public _Weak_types<_Ty>::type, public _Ty { // stand-in for an assignable reference
public:
    static_assert(is_object_v<_Ty> || is_function_v<_Ty>,
        "reference_wrapper<T> requires T to be an object type or a function type.");

    using type = _Ty;

    template <class _Uty, enable_if_t<conjunction_v<negation<is_same<_Remove_cvref_t<_Uty>, myreference_wrapper>>,
        _Refwrap_has_ctor_from<_Ty, _Uty>>,
        int> = 0>
        myreference_wrapper(_Uty&& _Val) noexcept(noexcept(_Refwrap_ctor_fun<_Ty>(_STD declval<_Uty>()))) {
        _Ty& _Ref = _STD forward<_Uty>(_Val);
        _Ptr = _STD addressof(_Ref);
    }

    operator _Ty& () const noexcept {
        return *_Ptr;
    }

    _NODISCARD _Ty& get() const noexcept {
        return *_Ptr;
    }

    template <class... _Types>
    auto operator()(_Types&&... _Args) const -> decltype(_STD invoke(get(), _STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...)) {
        return _STD invoke(get(), _STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
    }

private:
    _Ty* _Ptr;
};

template<typename T>
using view = vector<myreference_wrapper<const T>>;
int main() {
    C c;
    view<C>v;
    v.push_back(c);
    v[0].fun();
    return 0;
}
```

> class myreference_wrapper is copied from std header, just modified its inherit.

The solution is not very good, it can not solve basic types, but I can't gave a better one.

Actually, I think the perfect solution may not exist. `vector<reference_wrapper<const T>>::operator[]` returns type `reference_wrapper<const T>`, how can you deal with `reference_wrapper<const T>` the same as T? emm...Perhaps my knowledge is not rich enough.

Comment: I thought many times, I think the best way is creating a View class to warp vector by yourself. Just like what @Emerald Weapon said.